# How to prove the following formula using indirect proofs?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I have to prove the conclusion $(A \to B) \vee (B \to C)$ using nothing but formal proof rules for propositional logic (so introduction and elimination rules). Here's what I've done so far.

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZfz.png)

Basically, I've assumed the negation of the conclusion and my goal of the sub-proof is to prove a contradiction. After assuming the negation, I was able to prove that $\neg(A \to B)$ and $\neg(B \to C)$ which means I can say that 
$\neg(A \to B) \wedge \neg(B \to C)$ is true under this assumption. The problem now is that I have no idea where to go from here. All I need to do is show a contradiction but I have no idea how I would get to that contradiction.

P.S. This proof doesn't have any premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not have a contradiction in your negated statement if both expressions $A \to B$ and $B\to C$ are false. $A\to B$ can only be false if $B$ is false. But if $B$ is false then $B\to C$ is always true. Therefore at least one of the expressions will be true, which makes the overall expression always false, thus leading to a contradiction. (When in doubt, just do truth tables).

---

You can also use the fact that the negation of $P\to Q$ is $P\wedge\neg Q$. Therefore we have 
$$A\wedge\neg B\wedge B\wedge\neg C$$

Since $\neg B\wedge B$ is always false, you have a contradiction (the overall negated expression is false no matter what the truth values of $A$, $B$, and $C$ are).

I'll let you add in all of the formal labelings of each step.